# DataGridComboBoxColumn with Enum Converters is not working as expected

Tags: wpf, mvvm, enums, datagrid, converters

I have two converters.One for displaying Enum names and other for converting selected item value to type Enum before passing information to viewmodel.

Everything works fine with combo box.But the same is not working with DataGridComboBoxColumn inside a DataGrid.What am i missing?

```
class DetectionChemistryDisplaynameListProvider : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var listOfDetectionChemistry = new List<string>();

        listOfDetectionChemistry.Add(Enum.GetName(typeof(DetectionChemistryTest), DetectionChemistryTest.Hybridization));
        listOfDetectionChemistry.Add(Enum.GetName(typeof(DetectionChemistryTest), DetectionChemistryTest.Hydrolysis));
        listOfDetectionChemistry.Add(Enum.GetName(typeof(DetectionChemistryTest), DetectionChemistryTest.Intercalating));
        listOfDetectionChemistry.Add(Enum.GetName(typeof(DetectionChemistryTest), DetectionChemistryTest.Others));

        return listOfDetectionChemistry;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

second converter

```
 class DetectionChemistryConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var selectedEnumvalue = (DetectionChemistryTest)value;

        var selectedEnumName = Enum.GetName(typeof(DetectionChemistryTest), selectedEnumvalue);

        return selectedEnumName;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var selectedEnumName = (string)value;

        var selectedEnumValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(DetectionChemistryTest), selectedEnumName);

        return selectedEnumValue;
    }
}
```

Xmal for Resources

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:DetectionChemistryDisplaynameListProvider x:Key="displayEnumNameConverter" />
    <converters:DetectionChemistryConverter x:Key="enumValueConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Xmal For Combo Box with is working fine

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource displayEnumNameConverter}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboDetectionChemistry, Converter={StaticResource enumValueConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Xmal for dataGrid which doesn't works

```
 <DataGrid  Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ChannelCombinations}" CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Channel" Binding="{Binding ChannelCombinationName}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="DetectionChemistry" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource displayEnumNameConverter}}" 
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedDetectionChemistry, Converter={StaticResource enumValueConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Say my model looks something like

```
public class ChannelCombinationTest
{
    public string ChannelCombinationName { get; set; }

    public DetectionChemistryTest SelectedDetectionChemistry { get; set; }
}

public enum DetectionChemistryTest
{
    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    Hydrolysis = 0,

    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    Hybridization = 1,

    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    Intercalating = 2,

    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    Others = 3,
}
```

And my ViewModel is having ObservableCollection of ChannelCombinationTest.
This collection is binded to my datagrid.

I am following MVVM. So i cant afford to use Object Data Provider for my Enum Model.Please suggest accordingly.

Comment: Please do not use comments to add information to your own post. Click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43703363/edit) and add your comments that way. Please _do_ make sure you've provided a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. This means making sure **both** that you have not given us any code that is not _strictly_ required to reproduce the problem, and that you have given us _all_ of the code that is needed to reproduce the problem, i.e. a _complete_ program. The above meets neither requirement. See also [ask], including the articles linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Ok sure. Will try to improve the quality progressively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that WPF moves in mysterious ways its wonders to perform.

The reason the combo box list does not appear is that WPF needs a governing framework element for the items source.  You fix it like this...

```
    <FrameworkElement x:Name="dummyElement" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <DataGrid  Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ChannelCombinations}" CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Channel" Binding="{Binding ChannelCombinationName}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="DetectionChemistry" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource displayEnumNameConverter},Source={x:Reference dummyElement} }" 
                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedDetectionChemistry, Converter={StaticResource enumValueConverter}}"
                                />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="DetectionChemistry" Binding="{Binding SelectedDetectionChemistry, Converter={StaticResource enumValueConverter}}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much.You saved my day.